# DataTables object retrieval

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jQuery dataTables version 1.9.2

Table is created with class `datatable` and displayed properly but now I want to use  `fnPageChange` hence I need object of the table.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var oTbl = $(".datatable").dataTable();
    });
```

This code gives alert that says -

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'tblCat'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.    
To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or
see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy.
```

I read that Version 1.7 fixed this issue regarding popup [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2913/how-to-get-the-otable-datatable-object-from-the-tables-id/p1).

How can I get the existing object of the table to work with ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have done is-
while initializing the datatable `'bRetrieve':true` was added to the code.

And the I was able to get the object of the existing table and further I am able to navigate through the page using  `fnPageChange`.

This worked for me at least for now, lets c if this generates any new problems in future...:)

Following code worked.

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
  // column count starts with 0
  var oTbl = $('.datatable').dataTable(
   {"sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
   "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
   "bFilter": false,
   "bInfo" : false,
   // list of columns those will be unsortable
   "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 6 ] }],
   "bRetrieve":true,
   "oLanguage": {"sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"}} );
   // default sorting on this column
   oTbl.fnSort( [ [5,'desc'] ]);
  });
```

Comment: It sounds like you solved the problem.  Please post your code to "get the object of the existing table".

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $content.find("table.datatable").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bRetrieve":true,
        "bDestroy": true
    });
};
```

Comment: It would be better if you could add an explanation of what this code is doing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I came across this answer in the Review Queue, and sorry to be off-topic. But do you 'Recommend Deletion'  here, or do you leave a comment like yours and say "Looks Good"?

Comment: @Gray I don't recommend deletion for this type of answer because the code might be useful by itself.  The answer would be *greatly* improved if it had an explanation, but half an answer is better than no answer. I just leave a comment and click "Looks Good."

Comment: line 1:- Find the data table plugin initialization. add Line 2,3 and 4  to get rid of warning message when customized the grid. for example: $(function() {var table= $('#id').data table({"a a Sorting":[[0,"desc"]]}}););

Comment: This is incorrect: if bRetrieve is set, bDestroy is ignored. Pick the one you want and remove the other one, because including both does nothing.